# Saving masked value using ngx mask

Tags: angular, mask

I am using ngx mask with phone configuration like (00) 0000-0000 OR (00) 00000-0000 but when showing the user is not working.

Ex:

```
        <mat-form-field class="flex-1">
            <mat-label>Telefone</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="telefone" prefix="+55 " mask="(00) 00000-0000 || (00) 0000-0000">
            <mat-error *ngIf="this.mainForm.get('telefone').invalid">Informe o telefone</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field> // WORKING FINE
```

But when i show the number it is not configurated correctly.

```
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="telefone">
                        <th class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-black dark:bg-opacity-5" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef
                            mat-sort-header disableClear>
                            Telefone
                        </th>
                        <td class="pr-8 truncate" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                            {{row.telefone | mask: '(00) 00000-0000 || (00) 0000-0000'}}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container> // IT IS NOT WORKING. If the number is (21) 1234-4321 is appearing (21) 12344-321.
```

Comment: did you tried to change the order of patterns? `(00) 0000-0000 || (00) 00000-0000`

Comment: it doesn't work. I think "||" is not working when showing the value, only on input.